# what is the difference between component and framework?

Tags: frameworks, components

I know it's too straightforward but I'm confused about this. Imagine a library like JQuery and a component like telerik, which one is on top of another in producing? is it possible to use a framework in component development? what's the main difference between them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic on Stack Overflow, because it could be answered by google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Component:**

- A `Component` is essentially a set of functions that you can call,
  these days usually organized into classes. Each call does some work
  and returns control to the client.
- A `Component` you can use whatever tiny part helps you.
- A `Component` is a tool.

**Framework:**

- A `framework` is a skeleton where the application defines the "meat"
  of the operation by filling out the skeleton. The skeleton still has
  code to link up the parts but the most important work is done by the
  application.
- A `Framework` is a way of life.
- A `Framework` you must commit your entire project to.

**Best Real time Example:**

You can call `Component`. But you cannot able to call `Framework`.

`Framework` calls you. But `Component` not calls you.